# Web Api - IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 500.21 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Accessing web api's ***Delete*** operation returns below error. It does not even hit the break point.

```html
        [HttpDelete]
        public void Delete([FromUri]string id)
        { 
            // Deletion logic
        
        }
```

***IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 500.21 - Internal Server Error***

Comment: How are you trying to access delete endpoint using browser or some other tool? Is your website running under IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: The whole error page is telling you the reason (while you just pasted the useless fragment above).

Comment: I eventually found the solution for this issue. I needed to add below configuration in the config to make it work.    <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> 
    </modules>